# magento migration from 1.9.4.1 to 2.3.2 customers exception

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, magento2.3, data-migration-tool

I'm doing migration tests from Magento 1.9.4.1 to Magento 2.3.2.

**Setup: magento2, Ubuntu 18.04 php-7.2 nginx**

When I try to view the list of clients I get the following exception:

https://pastebin.com/mzVQYVkQ

anyone know how i could solve?

Thank you.

Comment: the problem is related to the custom customer attribute plugin, I'm working in the most correct way to be able to transfer even these "custom data"

Comment: Have you confirm that from table, does customer comes there or not ?